# How to pass route and additional route params to a partial twig template

Tags: symfony, templates, routes, twig, parameter-passing

I would like to use one partial twig template which creates a list of brands on different pages. The problem is, in different contexts we want to link to different routes. Some routes have an additional parameter (which can differ), others don't.

So the partial template may look like that:

```
<ul>
    {% for brand in brands %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path(route, {'brand': brand.name, (routeExtraParamName): routeExtraParamValue}) }}">{{ brand.name }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And that would be how to use it:

```
{% include 'partials/brand_list.html.twig' with { "brands" : brands, "route" : "brand", "routeExtraParamName": "something", "routeExtraParamValue": "test" } only %}
```

But this is not very nice. We often see similar problems like that, we want a clean interface to the partials, and they should not know about the context where they are used. But such a simple tasks like changing a link with additional parameters makes that much more difficult.

Do you have ideas for a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array with all route parameters and send it directly into your partial template:

```
{% set params = {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value 2', 'param3': 'value 3' %}

{% include 'partials/brand_list.html.twig' with { "brands" : brands, "route" : "brand", "route_params": params } %}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the other way I thought about. What I don't like here is defining data structures or variables at all in a twig template, that's something I always try to avoid.